myasp.net - deployServer FTPError: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
This is my error:

deployServer - FTPError: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

This is my yaml code for doing the continuous deployement:
name: Deploy server
on:
push:
branches:
- main
jobs:
deployServer:
runs-on: windows-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Setup .NET Core
uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
with:
dotnet-version: 8.0.x

- name: Install dependencies
run: dotnet restore
- name: Configure Git
run: |
git config --global core.fsmonitor false

- name: Build with dotnet
run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
working-directory: ./Biblia_Commentatione

- name: Test
run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal

- name: Install EF Core tool
run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

- name: Restore tools
run: dotnet tool restore

- name: Migrate
run: |
cd Biblia_Commentatione
dotnet tool restore
dotnet ef database update --connection "${{ secrets.CONNECTION_STRING }}"
cd ..

- name: Setup .NET Core
uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
with:
dotnet-version: 8.0.x

- name: Publish
run: dotnet publish -c Release --output ./bin/Release/.net8.0
working-directory: ./Biblia_Commentatione

- name: FTP Deploy
uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4
with:
server: win5161.site4now.net
username: ${{ secrets.MYASP_USERNAME }}
password: ${{ secrets.MYASP_PASSWORD }}
local-dir: ./Biblia_Commentatione/bin/Release/.net8.0/
server-dir: BibliaCommentatione/

So when I restart the pool and I run the workflow again, sometime it works for the second try
But this error happen at each time that the action is triggered (merging a pull request in master branch)   I think it is because the app is active.
What I want: find a solution so that I am able to make the continuous deployment work for my app at each time without having the file blocked so I have to rerun manually while restarting the pool as needed.
What do you think I can do? Do you think my script is wrong at some place?
I was wondering also the source of the problem: why does my file is blocked all the time, did I made somthing that I should not?...
So I was thinking about:

Find a way to restart the pool each time that the contunious deployment is triggered in my yaml script
Find a way to make myasp.net unable to block any file

But how to make these working, I do not know. Maybe you could help me with this problem?
Just wondering, am I the only client of myasp.net that have problem with my continuous deployment or it is a known issue with myasp.net?

I was able fix it by uploading the file before uploading the content.
I created a task that uploads a file named app_offline.htm. This will make the servers stop the AppPool, after this, I execute the task to upload my content.
It's necessary to enable the "Clear remote directory contents" to ensure that the app_offline file will be deleted and the AppPool will be started again.
